# Elasticsearch java-api spring-data should not index null value fields

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch java-api in combination with spring-data and have a problem with indexing a document. The indexing works but some values should be skipped. But first I show you my setup:

Domainobject:

```
@Document(indexName = "testindex", type = "message")
public class MessageObject {

@Id
private String  unid;

private String message;

private String secondMessage;

private String thirdMessage;

...

getters & setters

...

}
```

Interface:

```
public interface MessageObjectRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<MessageObject, Long> {


}
```

Service:

```
@Component
public class MessageService {

    @Autowired
    private MessageObjectRepository repository;


    public void addRegistrationObject(MessageObject msg) {

        repository.save(msg);
    }
}
```

So....

if I want to index a message which has only two messages set.  e.g. the "message" and the "thirdMessage" and I'm leaving the "secondMessage" null...

If I check my index it results in the following:

```
"hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "testindex",
        "_type": "message",
        "_id": "00113B325ED357B7C1257E2D001D5B4B",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "unid": "00113B325ED357B7C1257E2D001D5B4B",
          "message": "Hello",
          "secondMessage": null,
          "thirdMessage": "Third",
....
```

My problem is, I don't want to have a **null** value field in my index.
I'm not able to find anything useful about it...

Is it possible if a field has a null value to just ignore it? (Don't put it in the index) So my indexed document would look like this:

```
  "unid": "00113B325ED357B7C1257E2D001D5B4B",
  "message": "Hello",
  "thirdMessage": "Third",
```

without the

```
 "secondMessage": null,
```

?

I don't want a query which ignores the null value fields. I want an index without null value fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to specify the following `@JsonInclude` annotation at the class level

```
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Document(indexName = "testindex", type = "message")
public class MessageObject {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I want. :)